# Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'edit/604c39ab5d06fb205c654043

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

what this does is it appends edit/postid
I want to append edit:postid without a /

```
[routerLink]="['edit',post.id]
{ path: "edit:postId", component: PostCreateComponent }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the route like this.
`{ path: "edit/:postId", component: PostCreateComponent }`
You cannot append without `/` something in the route.

Comment: http://localhost:3000/api/posts:id this is my restful api that i need to map this request

Comment: @RahulKumarChoudhary The api and your route doesn't make sense.
To map to the request API, you need a service which will create HTTP request and response.
I dont understand your question now.
Please be more specific what you want.
If you want to get data from backend and then to show in the UI Frontend, this will not work as you are trying.
As I said you need service which will `GET, POST, PUT` your data and then show to Frontend.